# Reload service configuration for ServiceHost?

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, wcf-binding

We have a WCF `SerivceHost` (self-hosted), XML-configured in App.config. The host has already been opened.

We want to change a specific configuration value in the service's binding at runtime (from code).

Unfortunately, our current approach:

```
((SomeBinding) _serviceHost.Description.Endpoint.Single().Binding).SomeProp = value;
```

does not work. The configuration is not "applied". How to force a configuration reload at runtime?

Comment: is it self hosting...i.e. hosted by some application ?

Answer (score 0):

A possible approach is this:

Modify the value in the config file at runtime (cannot find instructions for doing this, but the approach [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/youssefm/archive/2010/01/21/how-to-change-net-configuration-files-at-runtime-including-for-wcf.aspx) may give you a start)

Reload the config from file using:

```
ConfigurationManager.RefreshSection("system.serviceModel/bindings");
```

I don't think your current approach of having the config initially set in xml and then trying to update it via code once the service host has started will work.